# How to make gnome classic the default desktop using command line tools?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

How to make gnome classic the default desktop on natty using command line?

Answer (score 4):

1) Edit your ~/.dmrc file

```
nano ~/.dmrc
```

It should look something like the example below. There may be several lines relating to keyboard layout, language, etc, but you can ignore those.

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome
```

2) Replace gnome with whatever you want, in this case `gnome-classic`.

3) Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>X</kbd> to close.