# Can't get classic gnome desktop set permanently?

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

I have followed instructions to set the gnome classic as default desktop permanently here:
[How to make gnome classic the default desktop using command line tools?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37131/how-to-make-gnome-classic-the-default-desktop-using-command-line-tools)

But every time I reboot the ubuntu desktop comes up and the file is changed back.

How do I set the classic gnome desktop permanently?

Comment: You're aware that 11.10 uses Gnome 3 right?, and that you'll have TONS of conflicts should you want to use Gnome 2.

Comment: possible duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: It's supposed to remember your last session every time you login, is it not doing that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Oneiric (Ubuntu 11.10) with autologin on lightdm? It seems similar to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/834515 which just got fixed in a proposed update to Oneiric, if that's the issue the fix should reach stable updates in the next week.